# SImple for loop--- I don't get it

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't really understand why the output below is given.

```
  for i in 'ab':
      for x in 'xy':
          print(i,x)
```

why does the output give

```
  a x
  a y
  b x
  b y
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'd expect it to give. What part of it don't you understand? What did you expect it to give?

Comment: There are any number of things here that could confuse a beginner. The fact that strings are iterables, the variable assignment in a for loop, nested loops in general, the implicit spaces in `print` output, to name a few. Could you be specific as to what you find unclear?

Comment: I thought it would give  a x   b y on a separate line

Comment: but Mayank's answer clarify my misunderstanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works like this:

```
for i in 'ab':
      for x in 'xy':
          print(i,x)
```

The first for loop `for i in 'ab':`, the value of `i` in 1st iteration will be `a` and in the inner loop `for x in 'xy'`, value of `x` in 1st iteration will be `x`.

So, the print statement prints `a x`
Similarly, in 2nd iteration, `i` is still `a` and `x` is `y`,so it prints `a y`.

Now, for 3rd iteration `i` becomes `b`, and `x`(inner loop variable) becomes `x`, hence, it print `b x`.

Similarly, it prints `b y` for 4th iteration.

Let me know if this helps.